Installing gEcon on a Linux - Debian 12 system
I wish to install:
https://gecon.r-forge.r-project.org/
on a Debian 12 system.
I have tried :
sudo R CMD INSTALL gEcon_1.2.2.tar.gz after downloading the tarball.
When I do that I get this message:
parser/model_parse.cpp: In function ‘void report_errors(const std::string&)’:
parser/model_parse.cpp:41:13: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   41 |     Rf_error(('\n' + mes).c_str());
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parser/model_parse.cpp: In function ‘void report_warns(const std::string&)’:
parser/model_parse.cpp:53:12: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   53 |     warning(('\n' + mes).c_str());
parser/model_parse.cpp: In function ‘void write_info(const std::string&)’:
parser/model_parse.cpp:64:12: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   64 |     Rprintf((mes + '\n').c_str());
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:204: parser/model_parse.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gEcon’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/gEcon’


The documentation of gEcon says:
that we may ignore warnings while installing gEcon on Linux.
Hence I tried creating a file : ~/.R/Makevars with the following content:
CFLAGS = -w

and then installing but that did not work.
I have also tried doing:

devtools::install_github("b2b-web-id/gEcon")
devtools::install("gEcon") after extracting the tarball.

They give similar errors.
(I should say that the Github version of the package seems to be behind the R-forge version. I would like to install from R-forge).
